# Is total order and total chaos equal?

Tags: information

Imagine an ideal gas which possesses maximum entropy. It´s not difficult to describe the state of the system because once you know some part of the system you can say how the whole system looks like. Now imagine a solid that consists of the same atoms but arranged in a crystal. Again you don´t need much information to say how the whole crystal looks like. The entropy for the the gas is nonetheless very much greater (there are so many possible states of the gas) than the entropy of the crystal, but to tell what both look like overall little information is needed. How is this possible?

Comment: Just because of "overall". You can't know the states of the particles for sure. You can only predict the macroscopic properties of the ideal gas.

Comment: Homogeneity goes a long way to simplify the physics of systems. Having said that, neither gases nor perfectly ordered solids are "simple" systems by any means. If you want to know how complex these systems are, there are entire sections of the physics library devoted to both.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because of how [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) is defined:

> a measure of the number of **specific realizations or microstates** that may realize a thermodynamic system in a defined state specified by macroscopic variables

It does not matter how easy it is to describe some general properties of the system, entropy measures how disordered is the system *at the microscopic level*.